# Making ajax call a repetative function so i can call it again n again

Tags: jquery, ajax

how can i make a J query ajax function so whenever i needed it i just passed a parameter to it instead of writing whole code again and again for example
here is an ajax code

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "ajax/select.php",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                $.each(data, function (index) {
                    $("#names").append("<li>"+data[index].name+"</li>")
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

now if i wanted to make another ajax request with to a page i have to write these line of code with different URL data and message how can i make it in a function so u just push parameter to it and it works form me 
like

```
<script>
    function multiple_calls(url, datatype, success) {
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            dataType: datatype,
            success: success
        });
    }
</script>
```

and called it anywhere i wanted to its just a demo but can someone suggest me how can i do it ? and please avoid negative marking as i m about to block please its a humble request

Comment: What is wrong with your current solution? Have you even tried it?

Comment: @charlietfl maybe the space in function name ;) but yeah - it looks quite good.

Comment: i have tried it but it said  function is not defined even if i defined it i m not good with jquery and ajax can someone help me making me one i need to write lots of ajax call and it drives me crazy lots of time wasted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few modification in your function. You can also pass the request parameters,type dynamically in the function.

```
//external function called while ajax success event fired.
var successFn = function(data)
{
    console.log(data);
}

//ajax call function 
function ajaxcall(url,type,data,dataType,successFn){
    $.ajax({
      url: url,
      type: type,
      data: data,
      dataType: dataType,
      success : successFn
    });
}
```

Comment: it works perfectly sorry for responding you late but thanks man

Answer (score 0):

Your suggested implementation is good.

Your first code shows a self-invoking function. Learn about them.

- [Ben Alman >> Immediately-Invoked Function Expression (IIFE)](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/)
- [Javascript Self Invoking Functions | Sarfraz Ahmed's Blog](https://sarfraznawaz.wordpress.com/2012/01/26/javascript-self-invoking-functions/)

You can store this function very similarly to your second code, instead use this:

```
<script>

    function ajaxSuccess (data) {
        $.each(data, function(index){
            $("#names").append("<li>" + data[index].name + "</li>");
        });
    }

    function ajaxCall (url, datatype, success) {
        $.ajax({
            url:url,
            dataType: datatype,
            success: success
        });
    }

    // Re-usable AJAX call
    ajaxCall("ajax/select.php", "json", ajaxSuccess);

</script>
```